# Conditional probability of continuous random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-probability

I understand that the formula for calculating a conditional probability is the following $P(A \mid B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)}$

I have this probability to calculate: $P(2\le X \le 3 \mid X \ge1)$.

What I would normally do is $P(2\le X \le 3 \mid X \ge1) = \frac{P(2\le X \le 3 \cap X \ge1)}{P(2\le X \le 3)}$.

However the numerator equals $P(2\le X \le 3)$. The above probability automatically becomes $1$ which is not right.

The textbook says the correct formula is this: $P(2\le X \le 3 \mid X \ge1) = \frac{P(2\le X \le 3 \cap X \ge1)}{P(X \ge1)}$.

Why is that? I thought the denominator is always the first part of the conditional probability like the first formula.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem#Statement_of_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula for calculating a conditional probability that you wrote is not correct; you should divide by $P(B)$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability

Comment: You are right, professor's notes were wrong. Thank you.